# How to disable USB Mouse only

Tags: drivers, mouse, linux-kernel, blacklist

I was developing a device driver for a USB mouse which uses the USB HID driver.
The problem is that I cannot test out my module as Linux takes over the mouse directly.

So how do I find out which modules I should blacklist so that only the mouse is completely disabled and I can test out my module and see its working.